# Can I change program data ID of the program account?

Tags: solana-program, getprogramaccounts, getaccountinfo

When fetching the program account using `getAccountInfo` rpc, it will return the following response:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "context": {
            "apiVersion": "1.17.6",
            "slot": 261230517
        },
        "value": {
            "data": {
                "parsed": {
                    "info": {
                        "programData": "CeWxs7Ytt4YAzKW7jtZtqdUJaAriwX5x3Gkt7cKqSFAF"
                    },
                    "type": "program"
                },
                "program": "bpf-upgradeable-loader",
                "space": 36
            },
            "executable": true,
            "lamports": 1141440,
            "owner": "BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111",
            "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
            "space": 36
        }
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

I know the actual program code is deployed at `CeWxs7Ytt4YAzKW7jtZtqdUJaAriwX5x3Gkt7cKqSFAF`.

However, is it possible to change the value of `programData` and make it switch to another data account with different program code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your question is not that clear, it is not possible to transfer the data stored in one program ID to another. You can very well create another program ID with exactly the same program code as the first one but you cannot get the data from the first program ID to the second one.